# Cordova - Trying to execute a function inside a webview

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, webview, inappbrowser

I have a webview from my website working very well in my app. What I'm trying to do now is asking users when they hit Android Back Button if they really want to leave the app.
I'm using the InAppBrowser plugin. Here's my code.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.splashscreen.show();
            var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br", "_self", "location=no");

            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
                ref.executeScript({
                    code:  
                        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
                        function onBackKeyDown() {
                            navigator.notification.confirm(
                                "Tem certeza que deseja sair?",
                                function(buttonIndex){
                                    confirmExit(buttonIndex);
                                },
                                "Aviso",
                                "Ok, Cancel"
                            );
                        }
                        function confirmExit(stat){
                            if (stat == "1"){
                                navigator.app.exitApp();
                            } else {
                                window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br", "_self", "location=no", "zoom=no");
                            }
                        };
                });
            });
        }
```

And here is the link of plugin
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#executeScript

Any idea what can i do to make it work ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please be more clear? What exactly do you want to do? Do you have trouble using in-app browser or the backbutton?

Comment: I'm having problem using the In-app Browser. I'm trying to inject some javascript inside my webview.

Comment: @ShinyJos after some debugging, I'm pretty sure my script is working. The real problem is that InAppBrowser looks like does not accept multi-lines code. I tried to use "file:" instead of "code:", but it did not work too.

Comment: Inapp-browser has trouble letting us get back to app, unless an external event closes the in-app browser. This is why your code behaves like that. I had faced the same issue and went with the alternate solution for webView as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your problem is back-button event is not getting triggered once the webview loads. This is a common problem with using in-appbrowser plugin for webview. It loads page but we loose control over the page. Use the following plugin
    https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizViewManager/ for webView. It creates a custom webview inside your phonegap app and you still have control over back button and you can also define the size of the webView